# Wagtail with Disqus

Tags: django, disqus, wagtail

Does Wagtail goes well with [django-disqus](https://django-disqus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

[THIS](http://danielhnyk.cz/adding-django-disqus-to-a-wagtail-site/) post made me a think that there might be issues on the way. Anybody have any experiences with using/integrating both?